# jQuery DataTable events not firing

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have a datatable that i dynamically initialise thru ajax's call and i have attached the click event on the table cell(td) hover when i try to click the cell i don't get the click event being fired, i am wondering what could be the cause. Here is the snippet

```js
let table = $('#data-table').DataTable();


$(document).ready(function()
{
    

    $("#data-table tbody").on("click", "td", function ()
    {
        console.log('Datatable was clicked')
    });


});

window.onload = function()
{
    table = $('#data-table').DataTable({
            destroy: true,
            responsive: true,
            serverSide: false,
            autoWidth: false,
            paging: true,
            filter: true,
            searching: true,
            stateSave: true,
            scrollX: true,
            lengthMenu: [5,10, 25, 50, 75, 100],
            ajax: {
                url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos',
                type: 'GET',
                dataSrc: ''
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    title: 'User Id',
                    data: 'userId',
                },
                {
                    title: 'Id',
                    data: 'id',
                },
                {
                    title: 'Title',
                    data: 'title',
                }
              ]
    });
    
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<table id="data-table" data-order='[[1,"asc"]]' class="table table-bordered table-hover">
      <thead>
          <tr class="primary">
              <th>User Id</th>
              <th>Id</th>
              <th>Title</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody></tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"> </script>
```

Comment: Your snippet doesn't work. `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: There are multiple syntax errors in you snippet. The document.ready is malformatted which is also making window.onload malformatted. I'm not going to fully check your syntax for all the errors. Please fix the snippet and we can go from there.

Comment: Sorry, i fixed the errors, there were missing a couple of brackets..

Comment: Your jQuery `$("#data-table tbody").on("click"...` should be inside some form of doc.ready. You might be asking jQuery to do something before jQuery itself is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues that really just boil down to typo's and bad syntax. The main take-home from this is to use the browser's console (it literally tells you what the problem is).

Here's a cleaned up version. Note that I've manually added a row of `td`s since your event listener is listening for clicks on `tbody>td` and there are none until and unless the ajax returns some (which it won't in a snippet)

```js
let table;

$(function(){

    $("#data-table tbody").on("click", "td", function(){
        console.log('Datatable was clicked')
    });

    table = $('#data-table').DataTable({
        destroy: true,
        responsive: true,
        serverSide: false,
        autoWidth: false,
        paging: true,
        filter: true,
        searching: true,
        stateSave: true,
        scrollX: true,
        lengthMenu: [5,10, 25, 50, 75, 100],
        ajax: {
            url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos',
            type: 'GET',
            dataSrc: ''
        },
        columns: [
            {
                title: 'Zone',
                data: 'LastKnownZone',
            },
            {
                title: 'Hiérarchie Map',
                data: 'MapInfo.mapHierarchyString',
            },
            {
                title: 'Addresse MAC',
                data: 'macAddress',
            }
          ]
     });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<table id="data-table" data-order='[[1,"asc"]]' class="table table-bordered table-hover">
      <thead>
          <tr class="primary">
              <th>Zone</th>
              <th>Hiérarchie Map</th>
              <th>Addresse MAC</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody><tr class="fordemopurposes">
              <td>1</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
          </tr></tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"> </script>
```

Comment: I appreciate! Is there a way of attaching event listerner to data-table when the table is loaded dynamically ? I mean thru some callback functions of data-table ?

Comment: @Xris Yes, [Datatable has its own events you can listen for](https://www.datatables.net/reference/event/). Or if you want to add your own listeners you can use jQuery's [event-delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to listen for and fire events on descendants that exist now or are added in the future.